# A class contains an array of objects. Do I need to set each of them to nothing on terminating the containing class?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working with code something like the below. An array of `BasketItemViewModel` is created in the scope of the `Basket` class by looping DB results and creating a view model from each row.

When I ditch the `Basket` class, and Set it to nothing, am I required to loop through the array of `BasketItemViewModel` and set each of those to nothing too?

```
Class Basket

    public GuidId
    public BasketItemViewModels
    public TotalItems
    public TotalCost

    Public Property Get TotalCostFormatted()
        TotalCostFormatted = FormatCurrency(TotalCost,0)
    End Property



    public Default function Init(p_GuidId, p_TotalItems, p_TotalCost)
        GuidId = p_GuidId
        BasketItemViewModels = GetBasketItemViewModels()
        TotalItems = p_TotalItems
        TotalCost = p_TotalCost
        set Init = Me
    end function 

    public function GetBasketItemViewModels()
        dim vmArray()

        for each row in dbResults
            // ...get some values...
            set vmArray(i) = (new BasketItemViewModel) (price, quantity, productId)
        next           

        GetBasketItemViewModels = vmArray
    end function 
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. It's not necessary. When your `Basket` object is destroyed, the `BasketItemViewModels` array goes with it. And when it goes, all of the references held by that array are released.

Consider the following example:

```
Dim b
Set b = New Basket
Set b = Nothing
WScript.Echo "After"

Class Basket
    Public Eggs
    Sub Class_Initialize()
        Dim a(1)
        Set a(0) = New Egg
        Set a(1) = New Egg
        Eggs = a
    End Sub
End Class

Class Egg
    Sub Class_Terminate()
        WScript.Echo "Egg cracked."
    End Sub
End Class
```

The output produced by this code is:

```
Egg cracked.
Egg cracked.
After
```

proving that the `Eggs` array is emptied, and its references released, when the `Basket` object is destroyed.

Comment: Perfect answer thank you.   And a great example to boot :)